# R - find change across same days of week for multiple variables and agrregate

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr

With data like below

```
text = "
date,weekday,hour,a,b
12/2/2019,Mon,8,18.17183824,0.017741935
12/2/2019,Mon,9,18.11228506,0.020967742
12/9/2019,Mon,8,16.77932274,0.020322581
12/9/2019,Mon,9,16.97327971,0.019677419
12/3/2019,Tue,8,18.17183824,0.017741935
12/3/2019,Tue,10,18.11228506,0.020967742
12/10/2019,Tue,8,16.77932274,0.020322581
12/10/2019,Tue,10,16.97327971,0.019677419
"
df = read.table(textConnection(text), sep=",", header = T)
```

Need to find the change in the variables `a` and `b` on a weekday to weekday basis. 
Example for `a`, the change would be calculated as follows

1. Change for hour 8 on Mondays = (16.77932274 - 18.17183824)/18.17183824
2. Change for hour 9 on Mondays = (16.97327971 - 18.11228506)/18.11228506
3. Change for hour 8 on Tuesdays = (16.77932274 - 18.17183824)/18.17183824
4. Change for hour 10 on Tuesdays = (16.97327971 - 18.11228506)/18.11228506
5. Average change for variable `a` in the dataset = Avg of 1,2,3,4

Would appreciate help

For one variable, I would have converted from long to wide format and computed gain for each pair of same weekdays by adding `week`+number as a label for values for `a`. I find the challenge with  doing it for multiple variables - `a` and `b` here. My real data has more than these 2 variables

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can `group_by` `weekday` and `hour`, use `lead`/`lag` to get next/previous value and use `mutate_at` to apply it for multiple columns.

```
library(dplyr)
df %>%
  group_by(weekday, hour) %>%
  mutate_at(vars(a:b), list(change = ~(lead(.) - .)/.))

#  date       weekday  hour    a      b a_change b_change
#  <fct>      <fct>   <int> <dbl>  <dbl>    <dbl>    <dbl>
#1 12/2/2019  Mon         8  18.2 0.0177  -0.0766   0.145 
#2 12/2/2019  Mon         9  18.1 0.0210  -0.0629  -0.0615
#3 12/9/2019  Mon         8  16.8 0.0203  NA       NA     
#4 12/9/2019  Mon         9  17.0 0.0197  NA       NA     
#5 12/3/2019  Tue         8  18.2 0.0177  -0.0766   0.145 
#6 12/3/2019  Tue        10  18.1 0.0210  -0.0629  -0.0615
#7 12/10/2019 Tue         8  16.8 0.0203  NA       NA     
#8 12/10/2019 Tue        10  17.0 0.0197  NA       NA
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is an option with `data.table`

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df)[, c('a_change', 'b_change') := 
    (shift(.SD, type = 'lead') - .SD)/.SD , .(weekday, hour), .SDcols = a:b]
```